# rep cap and accepted answers

Tags: discussion, bug

Yesterday I hit the rep cap thanks to some unexpectedly well received answers.

Here is what I don't understand: I got three answers accepted, which I thought should give me 45 "cap free" points. Add to that 200 "capped" points should get me to 245 - but somehow I was capped at 235 (with a lot of upvotes that carried no points but got me two "nice answer" and one "enlightened" badges).

Here is my question: I saw there was a "late in the day" vote reversal which removed 10 points - but this reversal did not "promote" a previously uncounted +10 ...

Is this expected behavior? I don't want to appear like I'm whining (OK I probably failed there) - I just want to understand.

**UPDATE** screenshot of rep tab https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26969/floris?tab=reputation :

[image]

While https://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation shows

```
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134932 (10)
 2    134932 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134935 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 1    134932 (15)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    134953 (10)
 2    135024 (10)
 2    135024 (10)
 2    134793 (10)
 2    134793 [10]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 1    135024 [15]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    134793 [0]
 2    134791 [0]
 2    134793 [0]
 2    134953 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    134953 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    134932 [0]
 2    134953 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    134793 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135078 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135078 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    135078 [0]
 2    135024 [0]
 2    134793 [0]
 1    134793 [15]
 2    135024 [0]
```

```
-- 2014-09-11 rep +245  = 10335
```

I did the sum of rep increments on the entire file - and it looks like I did indeed get credited with 245 points although the reputation tab says I got 235.

In other words - I have to (re)tag this as a bug, not a discussion...

Comment: I was halfway through writing up an epic analysis explaining your rep for that day, when I realized I didn't fully understand the rep rules. I now agree something looks fishy (or I can't count), especially in light of what's said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219630). And apparently [one can no longer manually force a recalculation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005). But it may be worth seeing if http://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation matches http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26969/floris?tab=reputation for you.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - not, the two links have different information but the same total... The former says I got 245 on 9/11/14 (as I should) while the latter shows 235. I updated the question with this information. So Martijn's post is still correct - but there is a bug in the rendering on the reputation tab.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can add another example to your rep-exhibiting bug. On Academia.SE, [my only question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24554/overlapping-sentences-in-methodology-descriptions-in-separate-journal-articles) was upvoted 11 times, then a few days later, a ''User removed'' brought it down to 10. Rep had a -10 as usual, but somehow, though it has been many days, on the [main SE account](http://stackexchange.com/users/4462950/new-new-newbie?tab=top), it still counts 11 for that question. So, I think the bug shows up only when there is a reversal/removal.

Comment: PS - Sorry, that's -5 not -10.

Comment: Such a *whiner*! But seriously, I've noticed this same "feature" (aka "bug") at other SE sites. I have maxed out a number of times at stackoverflow.com, a few times at other sister sites, and the behavior as implemented by software is never completely consistent with the behavior as explained in English.